# Is there a way to get an access token via Ubuntuone oauth?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

I'm working on a web app that includes a file export to Dropbox and Skydrive and i wanted to add UbuntuOne, too. That means i need access to files and if i understand the U1 API docs correctly the only oauth token with access to files is full access token:

https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud

But requesting a full access token requires the user to type in his username and password into my app, is that correct? Or is there another way to get a request a token with access to the user's files the same way a limited access token is requested, i.e. the user doesn't have to provide his username and password to my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is. As a web app, you may use the standard OAuth dance against Ubuntu One to obtain an OAuth token.

Use URLs https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/request to get a token, redirect the user to https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/authorize/?description=yourappname to have it authorized, and https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/access/ to convert it to a real token which you can save and use to authenticate requests on the user's behalf.

Comment: also, I'm happy to provide additional information and help if required; just drop me a line or chase me down on freenode IRC (as aquarius).

Comment: Thanks! This looks much like requesting a limited access token but without the app subfolder. Is this documented somewhere? If i try this with PHP OAuth it throws an exception, saying that most likely my consumerToken/Secret are incorrect. Do i have to use u1app, as in the limited access tokens or do i have to request unique tokens? If so, where can i get a consumerToken/Secret?

Comment: To clarify, for these tokens, use ubuntuone/hammertime as the consumer details.

Comment: @sil your first link (https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/request) returns 404

Answer (score 0):

This should work: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/883106/

There's some example code in a library I wrote that goes through these steps:
https://code.launchpad.net/restful-u1

Comment: This looks like it's using the Ubuntu SSO where my app needs the user's username and password which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No, this is how you get an access token the first time. Once you have the access token you can use it by signing the requests with the consumer/token pair as shown in the example.